# How to force 640*480@60Hz screen resolution on xubuntu 12.04

Tags: resolution, xorg, vga, xubuntu

It seems xubuntu won't be able to correctly set resolution at 640*480@60Hz at its Display settings. And I am unable to correctly my super small 6.4 inch Mitsubishi VGA panel via VGA cable.

I have tried to hack both X11 conf `/etc/X11/Xorg.conf` and xfce4 conf, but all the document I can find is outdated. and conf files are changed into other location.

Can someone give me a hand and I'll mark correct for other people to use? Thanks!

EDIT:
The board is an Intel Atom D2700, gpu is SGX545.

I tried to use `xrandr --output default --mode 640*480` It seems works fine, but refresh rate is 75Hz, but the screen only suports 60Hz

So I used  `xrandr --output default --mode 640*480 --rate 60` but it give error:

`xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default`

Can anyone pointing any directions?

Answer (score 2):

Try `xrandr --output default --mode 640*480 60`. This worked for me, at least until the reboot.

**EDIT**
just found this http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/666761

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ARandR](http://christian.amsuess.com/tools/arandr/), you can easily change your resolution using that.
Instructions are available [here](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2010/12/change-screen-resolutions-ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat-arandr/).

[image]

Comment: I tried to use `xrandr --output default --mode 640*480` It seems works fine, but refresh rate is 75Hz, but the screen only suports 60Hz

So I used  `xrandr --output default --mode 640*480 --rate 60` but it give error: `xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default`

Comment: that's not xubuntu's default (xfce) desktop, I suspect that tool might not be available (at least by default)...